# Creating or question in bootstrap form for better user experience

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, user-experience

I am building a user form that using `form-group` and `row`. I wanted to see what options you guys are using when you want the user to understand that this is an `or`?  The two questions are not require but they just need to under one of the question

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="enteredLink">Enter Link</label>
  <input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="txtLink" name="enteredLink" type="text" value="">
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="enteredFile">Upload File</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="txtFile" name="enteredFile" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem a bit simplistic, but have you considered a simple bit of text saying 'or'

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="enteredLink">Enter Link</label>
  <input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="txtLink" name="enteredLink" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="row"><p>or</p></div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="enteredFile">Upload File</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="txtFile" name="enteredFile" type="file" value="">
</div>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

It's not quite the same, but this is what the Gov.UK Design system does for radio button groups that are mutually exclusive - https://design-system.service.gov.uk/components/radios/#radio-items-with-a-text-divider

Edit - To highlight alternative used by SO

When posting this question I realised StackOverflow themselves do something similar to what you want. They essentially use an all in one box with clear calls to action to either drag and drop, browse or paste a link in

[image: Screenshot of StackOverflow image uploader]

Clicking 'paste' sticks the text box on screen for users to paste their link in

[image: Screenshot of StackOverflow image uploader paste text screen]

It'll slightly depend on who your audience is and how tech savvy they are, and also what people mostly will do as to what option is best.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this could work. There are two inputs for files and text. This makes it obvious that the user needs to pick one or the other.

```js
//optional display uploaded file into text input
function displayUpload() {
  var file = document.getElementById("txtFile").value;
  document.getElementById("txtLink").value = file;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group mt-5 px-5">
  <input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="txtLink" name="enteredLink" type="text" value="" placeholder='Enter link'>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary rounded-right" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('txtFile').click();">Or Choose file</button>
    <div class="custom-file" hidden>
      <input class="form-control" onchange='displayUpload();' id="txtFile" name="enteredFile" type="file" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And as a final note, I noticed that you named your IDs `txtFile` and `txtLink` if you would like to limit your file input you could also add `accept=".txt"` so the user could only upload .txt files.

Comment: I also have a drop zone that I wanted to use too. where users can drag-and-drop files. Also users can upload multiple files.